Looking for a c++20 typeof() equivalent
In a template function I would like to declare a vector (or set...) where T is the type of the data contained in another container.
Tried this under VisualStudio 17.9.7:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

template <class T> auto func(T const &data) {
  auto dummy = *begin(data);
  using Y = typename decltype(dummy);    // <---- DOES NOT COMPILE
  vector<Y> vec;
  for (auto x: data) vec.push_back(x);
  return vec;
}

void func1() {
  set<int> data({1,2,4,5});
  auto vec = func(data);
  for (auto y: vec) cout<<y<<endl;
}

However, in non-templated function this does compile and work as expected:
void func2() {
  set<int> data({1,2,3,4,5});
  auto dummy = *begin(data);
  using Y = typename decltype(dummy);    // <---- this is ok
  vector<Y> vec;
  for (auto x: data) vec.push_back(x);
  for (auto y: vec) cout<<y<<endl;
}

How can I get the template function to compile?

you don't need the typename portion

I am actually skeptical about keyword typename before decltype. I wouldn't be surprised if it didn't compile.

Remove the typename: using Y = decltype(dummy);. You use the typename keyword to tell the compiler that a dependent name is a type (because the compiler doesn't necessarily know when parsing the template -- it doesn't know what type you'll be giving it, so it can't know what T:x will actually be), but there's no dependent name following your typename.

Also, in C++20 a type name is known to be the only option after using Y =, so it doesn't have to be specified.

There are two ways to do this. First:
template <class T>
auto func(T const &data) {
  using std::begin;
  using Y = std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(*begin(data))>;
  std::vector<Y> vec;
  for (auto x: data) vec.push_back(x);
  return vec;
}

but you don't actually need to spell out the type:
template <class T>
auto func(T const &data) {
  using std::begin;
  using std::end;
  return std::vector(begin(data), end(data));
                //  ^ type inferred by iterators passed to std::vector::vector
}

Note also that in your original code, there was a critical error introduced by introducing dummy in case the passed container is empty.
